# Pandas shift column based on value of column below

Tags: python, pandas

With the following dataframe, I am trying to shift the `Price` column down by one only **when the price of the column below below is na** (or empty).

The initial df

```
+-----------+-------+
|  Client   | Price |
+-----------+-------+
| Desc of A |    20 |
| Client A  |       |
| Client B  |    30 |
| Desc of C |    10 |
| Client C  |       |
+-----------+-------+
```

would result in the below. Notice `30` didn't shift because in the column `price` of the row below, the field was not empty (was 10)

```
+-----------+-------+
|  Client   | Price |
+-----------+-------+
| Desc of A |       |
| Client A  |    20 |
| Client B  |    30 |
| Desc of C |       |
| Client C  |    10 |
+-----------+-------+
```

The example df:

```
d = {'Client': ['Desc of A', 'Client A', 'Client B', 'Desc of C', 'Client C',], 'Price': [20,np.nan ,30, 10,np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Pandas shift column based on value of column below

Comment: Why would you shift and create another blank in the column ? Better  you can go for forward filling `ffill`

Comment: The idea once this is done is to drop all na fields in the price column, so that in the end the 'Desc of XX' are dropped, and only the 'Client XX' and amounts are kept in the df.

Comment: is the logic always the same - do you want to move the value from `Desc of ...` to the child client ?

Comment: The logic is not always the same, the string in the 'Desc of ' is arbitrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this in two steps,

first lets write a boolean to measure null values.

```
nulls = df['Price'].isna()
```

Where this condition is true, grab the row above.

```
s = df['Price'].isna().shift(-1).fillna(False)
```

then assign those values to that row (the null row). we can use `.values` to assign as a list.

```
df.loc[nulls,'Price'] = df.loc[s,'Price'].values
```

then assign the moved values as nulls.

```
df.loc[s,'Price'] = np.nan
```

---

in one go.

```
nulls = df['Price'].isna()
s = df['Price'].isna().shift(-1).fillna(False)
df.loc[nulls,'Price'] = df.loc[s,'Price'].values
df.loc[s,'Price'] = np.nan

print(df)

      Client  Price
0  Desc of A    NaN
1   Client A   20.0
2   Client B   30.0
3  Desc of C    NaN
4   Client C   10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df.Price.ffill(inplace=True) # Forward fill to fill the na values.
df = df[~df['Client'].astype(str).str.startswith('Desc')] # remove rows where Client starts with 'Desc'
```